# PHP `array_push` with JSON

Tags: php

I have a `json` array (named `$ourData`) which currently looks something like this:

```
[
    //this item of $ourData named $officer_0
    {
        "code": "cg",
        "tots": [],
        "pds": []
    }
]
```

Now if I wanted to `push` some associative values to `tots` (something like `"date" : "value"`), how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($ourData, true);
$data['tots'][] = 'new data to add';
$ourData = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: That means that [0] does not exist in the array.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you do it [solution](https://tehplayground.com/6UpWJ4pA52QW63Pv)

```
$json = '[
    {
        "code": "cg",
        "tots": [],
        "pds": []
    }
]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$arr[0]['tots'][] = array("date" => date('Y-m-d'));

$json = json_encode($arr);

echo $json;
```